# Can I change the startup sound on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, big-sur

I wanted to find the audio file with the startup chime and either switch it with another one of mine or edit it but i can't locate the file.
Does anyone know of a way of finding this file or to get the same wanted result in another way?

Comment: If I remember correctly the chime is (was?) stored in NVRAM and not changeable. You can turn it off or on but that is about it. And the way things are going today someone will shortly prove me wrong...

Answer (score 4):

On an Intel Mac, the startup chime is part of the Mac's firmware. You can't just replace it, like you could a normal audio file.

Think about this logically—the startup chime plays as soon as you turn on your computer, before it loads the operating system. And if you wipe your hard drive, the sound will still play. How would that be possible, if the chime was stored on your drive?

Comment: Do you know where exactly this firmware is?  In NVRAM?

Comment: I doubt it's stored in NVRAM, that's for volatile storage. I don't know the intricacies of Apple's Mac firmware, but, trust me when I say this is really not something you want to mess with! The consequence of something going wrong is your Mac won't boot, at all.

Answer (score 4):

On Intel Macs with T2 chip, the startup sound is stored in there.
You can change the sound by jailbreaking it with Checkra1n.
0. You will need another Mac or Linux PC.

1. Jailbreak the T2 with Checkra1n.
2. Connect to it with SSH.
3. Convert the startup sound file to aiff.
4. Replace /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BridgeAccessibilitySupport.framework/AXEFIAudio_VoiceOver_Boot.aiff with that file. (Back up the original file before doing.)
5. Use the ‘snappy’ command to make the change permanent.

For more information, please refer to https://checkm8.info/blog/customize-macos-boot

Comment: Is the startup sound in the T2. Its impossible to change something on the T2 is not?

Comment: @DarwinOSX The answer describes how to change the startup sound *on* the T2.